# Delete <TR> conditionally

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a the first row of a table to display header text that will give meaning to a group of rows below it.

Upcoming Events

then looping thru the model to build a table listing of those upcoming events. But there may be client-side conditions that result in no rows being rendered which negates the need for the header row.

How can I reach back from the end of my 'Upcoming Events Iterator' and delete the first row (id="HeadRow")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need a header row, then you probably don't need the table, so why not just hide the entire table?

```
$("table").hide();
```

Then, later, if there is something to show, then you don't have to rebuild the header row, you can just update the table and make it visible.

Comment: Sometimes it's nice to let the user know that the query was successful, but didn't return anything.  In that case, I'd leave the table (and the header row), but indicate that no results were available.

Comment: I would agree, or at least have a div popup that will just display the lack of results and then fade away.  I just don't see the point of getting rid of the header row.

Answer (score 1):

I would take James Black's approach and hide the whole table if no rows exist rather then just removing the header row.

You can run a quick check after everything has fired to load the rows and hide the table if only the header row exists:

```
if ($("#myTable tr").length == 1) {
  $("#myTable").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr#HeadRow").remove(); 
// Removes <tr id='HeadRow'><td>foo</td>...</tr> from DOM
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure that you close the row so it's valid html, you can do this:

```
$("#headrow").remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than define your header row statically, I'd output it dynamically along with the rest of the table rows.  Like this, in pseudocode:

```
int numThings = 0;
for each (thing in dataModel) {
    if (thing.wantToDisplay()) {
       if (++numThings == 1) {
           outputHeaderRow();
       }
       outputThing(thing);
    }
}
```

By the way, you should probably be using <th> rather than <td>.

Answer (score 0):

Typically what I will do is leave the header row but insert a row with a nice, descriptive message indicating that there was nothing to show.

```
<table>
<thead>
   <tr><th>....</th></tr>
<thead>
<tbody>
   <% if (Model.Results.Count() > 0) {
         foreach (var model in Model.Results) { %>
           <tr>
             <td><%= Html.Encode( model.Name ) %></td>
             ...
           </tr>
   <%    }
      }
      else {  %>
           <tr><td colspan="N">Query returned no results.</td></tr>
   <% } %>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
  ...
</tfoot>
</table>
```